# Django and backbone templates

Tags: django, backbone.js

I have a working backbone application. The backend is Django.

I have a Detail View of posts that uses an underscore.js template with a bit of logic:

For example:

```
{[ _.each(model.images, function(i){ ]} <img src="{{i.image}}"> {[ }); ]}
```

I now want to create the server-side view, in order to serve the url `example.com/details/10`

What would be the best way of reusing the underscore.js template? Or should I just copy/paste it into another file and change it to the django templating language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look [here](https://github.com/thikonom/django-backbone-blog) to get an idea of how you could efficiently structure such an application.

The django app is inside the blog directory(look at the static/app.js)